# Feature importance for xgboost classification of a sample

Tags: random-forest, boosting

related to [Feature importance for random forest classification of a sample](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/174229/feature-importance-for-random-forest-classification-of-a-sample)

This [blog](http://blog.datadive.net/interpreting-random-forests/) by Ando Saabas suggests a nice way to interpret a tree result for a specific sample into per-feature contributions. Basically he goes over the path to the sample and counts each delta in the prediction $pred(currentNode) - pred(parentNode)$ as a contribution for the splitting feature.

Can I use a similar approach for interpreting results of gradient boosting with tree weak classifiers, specifically for the popular `xgboost` implementation?

Comment: This approach doesn't make a whole lot of sense because it doesn't account for the weights of the leaf nodes. Node weights are the "boosting" portion of the model, so ignoring them implicitly ignores the fact that you're using boosted trees.

Comment: this is also implemented in `eli5`, which includes `xgboost`/`lightgbm`/`sklearn`/'catboost`. https://github.com/eli5-org/eli5/blob/master/eli5/lightgbm.py

Answer (score 3, accepted):

since posting this, I learned that `xgboost` does make use of this method exactly, available when calling `predict(pred_contribs=True, approx_contribs=True)`.

Comment: Do you maybe know why the output is N features + 1? https://xgboost.readthedocs.io/en/stable/python/python_api.html (I am using pred_contribs only)

Comment: Nvm, from the documentation: "Note the final column is the bias term.".